# Expect either of two method calls in a loop in GoogleMock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I have a class `Foo` that references multiple other objects of type `IBar`. The class has a method `fun` that needs to invoke either `frob1()` or `frob2()` based on the number. I want to write a test with mocked `IBars` that verify this requirement. I'm using GoogleMock. I currently have this:

```
class IBar 
{ 
public: 
    virtual void frob1() = 0; 
    virtual void frob2() = 0; 
};
class MockBar : public IBar 
{ 
public: 
    MOCK_METHOD0(frob1, void ()); 
    MOCK_METHOD0(frob2, void ()); 
};

class Foo {
    std::shared_ptr<IBar> bar;
public:
    Foo(std::shared_ptr<IBar> bar)
        : bar(std::move(bar))
    {}
    void fun(int num) {
        for (int n = 1; n <= num; ++n) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) bar->frob1();
            else bar->frob2();
        }
    }
};

TEST(FooTest, callsAtLeastOneFrob) {
    auto bar = std::make_shared<MockBar>();
    Foo foo(bar);

    // HOW TO WRITE THE FOLLOWING EXPECT_CALL IN A LOOP?
    EXPECT_CALL(*bar, frob1()).Times(5);
    EXPECT_CALL(*bar, frob2()).Times(5);

    foo.fun(10);
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is what I have tried:

```
MockFunction<void()> check_point;
for (int count = 1; count <= 10; ++count) {
    EXPECT_CALL(*bar, frob1())
        .WillOnce(InvokeWithoutArgs(&check_point, &MockFunction<void()>::Call));
    EXPECT_CALL(*bar, frob2())
        .WillOnce(InvokeWithoutArgs(&check_point, &MockFunction<void()>::Call));
    EXPECT_CALL(check_point, Call())
        .Times(1);
}
```

When I run, I see the following error:

```
Expected: the expectation is active
Actual: it is retired
Expected: to be called any number of times
Actual: never called - satisfied and retired
```

I'm trying to mock the function in a loop. How do I write `EXPECT_CALL` in a loop?

Comment: Why you move a `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: And please write a question (not as a code comment). And what should the loop do?